# Send date and pagination in request body ,node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request

This is my API :
API:{{test}}/users/getDashboardDetails

Now I am sending the pagination in request body.
Request Body:
{
"pagination": {
"page": 1,
"limit": 10
}
}

Now I want to send date as well:
Request Body:
{
"start": "7/7/2022",
"end": "7/9/2022"
}
along with the pagination .

How can I send date and pagination in request body together?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your data in an object then send them together as you want like this,

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "limit": 10
    }
  },
  "date": {
    "start": "7/7/2022",
    "end": "7/9/2022"
  }
}
```